# Does nhibernate 5.2.3 support .netcore 2.1?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, asp.net-core-2.1

nhibernate nuget package docs
[image]

The nhibernate 5.2.3 docs say it supports .netcore 2.0 but 
Does nhibernate 5.2.3 also support .netcore 2.1?

Comment: yes it does....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NHibernate 5.1.3 or later support `.Net Standard 2.0`,  can be used with .net core 2.1 or .net framework 4.6.1 which support .net standard 2.0.

please refer to the repo https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity?files=1 for more information.