# How to make NHibernate 5.2.7 not have runtime exceptions with ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nhibernate, runtime-error, fluent-nhibernate

On a new project my team and I are working on, I'm exploring if NHibernate 5.2.7 / FluentNHibernate 2.1.2 are compatible with ASP.NET Core 3.1.  I did [some research on NHibernate 5.2.3, a slightly earlier version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533122/does-nhibernate-5-2-3-support-netcore-2-1), and in that SO thread, they noted that NHibernate at this point should be .NET Core compatible.

With that being said, that does not appear to be the case.

Below is how we use NHibernate.  We create sessions using this `DataContext` object (in a `using` block, of course, because `ISessions` are `IDisposable`!) and then use QueryOver to fetch or set data to our database.

However, when we attempt any DB operations, we get the following exception on the `_sessionFactory.OpenSession()` call:

```
Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
Inner exception: null
Stack trace: at NHibernate.Impl.SessionIdLoggingContext.get_SessionId()
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionIdLoggingContext..ctor(Guid id)
  at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.BeginContext()
  at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl..ctor(ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, ISessionCreationOptions options)
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl..ctor(SessionFactoryImpl factory, ISessionCreationOptions options)
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.SessionBuilderImpl`1.OpenSession()
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenSession()
  at MyRadProject.Core.DataContext.GetSession() in C:\MyRadProject.Core\DataContext.cs:line 18
  at MyRadProject.Core.Repositories.UserRepository.GetUsers(Boolean includeInactive) in C:\MyRadProject.Core\Repositories\UserRepository.cs:line 23
  at MyRadProject.Web.Controllers.CommonController.GetUsers() in C:\MyRadProject.Web\Controllers\CommonController.cs:line 21
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()
```

As far as my team can tell, this exception *previously* occurred in earlier versions of .NET Core due to certain namespaces or classes that weren't provided for in the .NET Core (e.g. `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`)  To the shared credit of .NET Core and NHibernate these issues seem to be much mitigated.

I double-checked that `mscorlib` was referenced in the library project that our data-access code exists in ("MyAwesomeProject.Core").  In Visual Studio 2019, I didn't see such a reference; when I attempted to manually reference `mscorlib`, I got a message, "mscorlib is automatically referenced by the build process."

All of this leads to my **question:**
*Assuming that the SO thread above is accurate in stating that NHibernate 5.1.1+ is .NET Core-compatible, what else do I need to do to make it such that NHibernate 5.2.7 does not generate a runtime exception when I attempt any database operation?*

**DataContext.cs**

```
public class DataContext
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private static bool _startupComplete;

    private static readonly object _locker = new object();

    public static ISession GetSession()
    {
        EnsureStartup();
        ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();  // EXCEPTION occurs here!
        session.BeginTransaction();
        return session;
    }

    public static void EnsureStartup()
    {
        if (!_startupComplete)
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (!_startupComplete)
                {
                    PerformStartup();
                    _startupComplete = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void PerformStartup()
    {
        InitializeSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        Configuration configuration = BuildConfiguration();
        _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static Configuration BuildConfiguration()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration().Configure();
        return Fluently.Configure(configuration)
            .Mappings(cfg => cfg.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(typeof(DataContext).Assembly))
            .BuildConfiguration();
    }

    // There are other methods below this point that aren't pertinent to the question.
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using .NET Core or .NET Standard version of the library? Try both just in case. And you should provide full exception stack-trace - inner exception should contain info where this exception is come from.

Comment: Roman - added the inner exception (null) and stack trace.  Verifying what library version is being used; I did install NHiberate by way of NuGet Package Manager, so _in theory_ it should be targeting .NET Core 3.1, since the project I'm using it on is a .NET Core project.  That being said, that's theory, that might not be what's actually up.

Comment: It's Full .NET Framework version. In .NET Core/.NET Standard AsyncLocal class is used instead CallContext

Comment: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/c0f50429722b4e061a0c6b40b720db17d33fc85e/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionIdLoggingContext.cs#L60-L65

Comment: That...is _really_ good to know.  Will see what I can do about making the correct library version get used.  Would you mind creating an answer out of this thread of discussion?

Comment: FluentNHibernate might be the culprit actually.If you are still in struggle :) try to force delete both packages and then firstly install NHibernate and only then FluentNHibernate.

Comment: Roman - Good news.  NHibernate, and FluentNHibernate weren't the problem.  I am.  I chose the wrong C# library type.  If you want stuff to be .NET Core compatible, you must choose a .NET Core library type; my .Core project was an old-style .NET Framework library project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Full .NET Framework version of the library as `CallContext` class is not used in .NET Core/.NET Standard version of NHibernate (`AsyncLocal` is used instead):
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/c0f50429722b4e061a0c6b40b720db17d33fc85e/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionIdLoggingContext.cs#L60-L65

So to fix your issue try to use .NET Core or .NET Standard version of the library.

Comment: So.  As with most silly problems, there is a silly cause (and answer.)  It turns out that, with the advent of .NET Core, there is a new C# .NET Core Library project type that is available.  If you add NuGet packages to a .NET Core library, they will be .NET Core packages.  If you don't, they won't.  My problem was that my ".Core" assembly was the old .NET Framework type, not the new .NET Core type.  That was the source of my problems.